# What is this layered effect with a swipe down modal called and how can I recreate it using react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've tried searching on all kind of different modals but found nothing related to this effect. I know I could recreate it myself, but I've seen a lot of apps use it in the exact same way so I thought there must be a tool or component that does this? [here is the effect I want to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZYTX.jpg)

Comment: Does this help? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#animationtype

Comment: @VictorF hah wauw, it was In the documentation at presentation style. Reminder for me to look more closely to the documentation. Thanks tho!